# debug.keystore does not exist at default location

Tags: flutter, firebase, keystore

I am making an app with flutter, and I need the sha1 and sha256 fingerprints for firebase. I found that for finding them **without android studio**, I need to run the command

```
keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

I changed user with my user but it says keystore file does not exist at that location. I checked, and it does not. Theres only one file called analytics.settings in the .android folder

I read that perhaps the debug.keystore is not created(Source may not be correct) so I built the app. But the keystore did not generate. I read on a medium article that the path for windows is at users/.keystore , but that folder does not exist for me.

Answer (score 0):

If You are using Android Studio, create the keystore by Android Studio and save it in your project path (ex: `yourrootprojectpath/android/keys/keystore`).

Alternatively, create your own keystore and store in `yourrootprojectpath/android/keys/keystore`.

Then configure your key information in `android/app/build.gradle`.

Example build.gradle:

```
android {
     ....
     signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('../keys/keystore')
            storePassword 'your_store_password'
            keyAlias = 'your_key_alias'
            keyPassword 'your_key_password'
        }
        release {
            storeFile file('../keys/keystore')
            storePassword 'your_store_password'
            keyAlias = 'your_key_alias'
            keyPassword 'your_key_password'
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

You can read more references here:

https://developers.google.com/android/guides/client-auth

https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing#kts